# Resetting JFrame

Tags: java, swing

This game is connect four and at the end of the game I give the player an option 
to play again. So if they want to play again I try clearing the canvas and resetting the board. I know basically nothing about doing java graphics so I'm 
pretty certain the error stems from me not understanding something about the 
graphics as opposed to the games logic.
If you look at the update gameState method right after I get input from the user
is when I try to reset everything. And when I say reset I mean remove all images and such from window. Instead of everything being removed it just locks up.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame
{
   public static final String GAME_NAME        = "Connect Four!";
   private static final int   _PLAYER_ONE_TURN = 1;

   private static String      _title;
   private Board              _gameBoard;
   private ToolBar            _buttons;
   private boolean            _humanVsHuman;
   private int                _gameIteration;


   public MainFrame()
   {
      super();

      final String INITIAL_GAME_MESSAGE = "Human Vs. Human? Default Computer "
            + "Vs. Human.";
      final String MENU_TITLE = "Game Setup...";
      final String[] MENU_OPTIONS = { "Yes!", "No!" };

      _gameBoard = new Board(Game.BOARD_WIDTH, Game.BOARD_HEIGHT);
      _buttons = new ToolBar(Game.BOARD_WIDTH);
      _humanVsHuman = 0 == JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this,
            INITIAL_GAME_MESSAGE, MENU_TITLE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, MENU_OPTIONS, MENU_OPTIONS[1]);

      updateTitle();
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      setSize(Game.SCREEN_WIDTH, Game.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
      setResizable(false);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      add(_buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      setVisible(true);
   }


   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
      GamePiece[][] board = _gameBoard.getBoard();
      _buttons.repaint();

      for (int x = 0; x < Game.BOARD_WIDTH; x++)
      {
         for (int y = 0; y < Game.BOARD_HEIGHT; y++)
         {
            if (board[x][y] != null)
            {

               g.setColor(
                     board[x][y].toString().equals(GamePiece.GAME_PIECE_BLUE)
                           ? Color.BLUE : Color.RED);
               g.fillOval((int) (x * (GamePiece.SIZE[0] * .92) + ((Game.SCREEN_WIDTH - (GamePiece.SIZE[0] * Game.BOARD_WIDTH)) / Game.BOARD_WIDTH) * x + 30), (int) (y * (GamePiece.SIZE[1] * .9) + ((Game.SCREEN_HEIGHT - (GamePiece.SIZE[1] * Game.BOARD_HEIGHT)) / Game.BOARD_HEIGHT) * y + 30),
                     GamePiece.SIZE[0], GamePiece.SIZE[1]);
            }
         }
      }
   }


   public void updateTitle()
   {
      final String HUMAN = "HUMAN";
      final String COMPUTER = "COMPUTER";
      final String PLAYER = "PLAYER";
      final String TURN = "TURN";

      _title = GAME_NAME + " " + Game.VERSION + ": " + PLAYER + " "
            + (getPlayerTurn(_gameIteration) == _PLAYER_ONE_TURN
                  ? _humanVsHuman ? "1" : HUMAN
                  : _humanVsHuman ? "2" : COMPUTER)
            + " " + TURN;

      setTitle(_title);
   }


   public void updateGameState(boolean aWinner)
   {
      final String AGAIN = "Play Again?";
      final String ROUND_OVER = "ROUND OVER";
      final String[] OPTIONS = { "Yes", "No" };
      boolean hasWinner = aWinner;

      if (hasWinner || _gameBoard.isFull())
      {

         if (hasWinner)
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                  getPlayerTurn(_gameIteration) == _PLAYER_ONE_TURN
                        ? "Blue won!" : "Red won!");
         }

         if (0 != JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this, AGAIN, ROUND_OVER,
               JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
               OPTIONS, OPTIONS[1]))
         {
            setVisible(false);
            dispose();
         }
         else
         {
            _gameBoard.clearBoard();
            removeAll();//or remove(JComponent)
            invalidate();
            _buttons = new ToolBar(Game.BOARD_WIDTH);
            updateMainFrame();            
         }
      }

      _gameIteration++;

   }


   public void updateMainFrame()
   {
      revalidate();
      repaint();
      updateTitle();

      if (_gameIteration + 1 == Integer.MAX_VALUE)
      {
         if (getPlayerTurn(_gameIteration) == _PLAYER_ONE_TURN)
         {
            _gameIteration = 0;
         }
         else
         {
            _gameIteration = 1;
         }
      }

   }


   private int getPlayerTurn(int iteration)
   {
      return (iteration % 2) + 1;
   }

   private class ToolBar extends JPanel
   {

      public ToolBar(int numberOfButtons)
      {

         setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,
               (int) (Game.SCREEN_WIDTH / numberOfButtons) / 2, 0));

         for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++)
         {
            JButton button = new JButton("" + (i + 1));

            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {

               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
               {
                  boolean hasWinner;

                  if (!_gameBoard
                        .isRowFull(Integer.parseInt(button.getText()) - 1))
                  {
                     hasWinner = _gameBoard.insert(
                           getPlayerTurn(_gameIteration) == _PLAYER_ONE_TURN
                           ? new BluePiece() : new RedPiece(),
                     Integer.parseInt(button.getText()) - 1);
                     updateMainFrame();
                     updateGameState(hasWinner);

                  }
               }

            });
            add(button);

         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: *"I know basically nothing about doing java graphics"* - Then you really should start by having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and 
[Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details, as you're violating two basic rules and I've not reached the end of  your code yet

Comment: You might also like to have a look at [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  The basic idea is that the game code should be isolated and free from the view and control code.  The view then uses the model to generate a representation of the model and the controller controls in the input from the user to update the state of the model, based on the rules of the model.  In this way, when you want to start a new game, you could simply create a new model